# When use createQuery() and find() methods of EntityManager?

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

I would like to know the difference between on these methods.

When use the `createQuery()`and `find()` methods of EntityManager ?

What the advantages about each of them ?

Thank you for answer me.

Comment: Have you read the Javadoc?

Comment: @Zutty Yes, I have, but I didn't understand very well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You use [`find`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object%29) when you want to look up an entity by primary key. That means you know exactly what you're looking for, you just want to pull it out of the database.

You use [`createQuery`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery%28javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery%29) when you want to find entities using criteria or if you want to use a JPQL statement to define what you get back. So you would use the query when you want to get an entity or collection of entities matching some conditions.

Comment: Thank you to reply. Then the advantages is the same for both. So depends what I'll search exactly.
Nice post link's. :-)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but .find() hits 2nd level cache, whereas createQuery will not

Comment: @Broccoli: createQuery uses the query cache, see https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-query-cache-work/

Answer (score 11):

The `createQuery` method allows you to create a JPQL statement that will be executed.  The JPQL statement allowed is much more dynamic than the one executed by `find`.  For example given the following table:

```
create table CAT(
   cat_id integer,
   cat_name varchar(40)
)
```

You could execute a query to find the cat by name.

```
entityManager.createQuery("select c from Cat c where c.name = :name");
```

The `find` method only allows you to retreive an object using its primary key.  So to use the `find` method for the above table:

```
entityManager.find(Cat.class, new Integer(1));
```

In a nutshell, `createQuery` allows you to retrieve entities in a more dynamic fashion, while `find` limits you to searching for an entity with a known id.

Comment: @Andriel Glad I could help do you have any lingering questions?

Comment: At moment its all ok! Thank you !! :-)